# Where does Ubuntu store the SSL certificates for Pidgin?

Tags: pidgin, ssl

Since today Pidgin stopped working and [the workaround is to "refresh the SSL certificate".](http://retrohack.com/why-cant-we-all-just-get-along/#more-3107)

Where is it stored?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They're stored here:

```
~/.purple/certificates/x509/tls_peers/
```

[I've seen](http://blog.andreineculau.com/2010/11/pidgin-and-msn-certificate-error-for-omega-contacts-msn-com/) that replacing `omega.contacts.msn.com`'s content with this fixes it for me (warning: there could be security implications for this):

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Comment: what is the exact format of the file in `~/.purple/certificates/x509/tls_peers/`?  [Import gmail certificate in Pidgin](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/351752/32012).

Answer (score 3):

Have you taken a look at this guide already: [Fix the Pidgin ‘SSL Error’ in Ubuntu [OMG!Ubuntu!]](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/11/fix-pidgin-ssl-error/) ?

From the aforementioned post:

> 1. Open https://omega.contacts.msn.com in your browser
> 2. You will get a directory access denied error  - for once it’s what we
>      want to see!
> 3. Click the ‘security’ or ‘padlock’ icon usually found to the left of the
>      URL in the address bar to view the
>      certificate.
> 4. Click around to find the ‘export certificate’ feature (In Chrome/ium
>      this is the ‘details’ tab)
> 5. Rename the exported certificate omega.contacts.msn.com and copy it to
>      the Pidgin certificates folder located
>      in your home folder at
>      .purple\certificates\x509\tls_peers\
>      (You’ll need to press CTRL+H to see
>      hidden files)
> 6. Overwrite the existing file with the one you’ve just exported
> 7. Breathe.  You’re done.

Comment: Well for me it has work but just for a while and now errors have restarted to pop up again randomly.

Answer (score 1):

in pidgin select 'Certificates' from 'tools' menu. Here you can manage ssl certificates. Just delete the old one and  click on the 'add' button to create a new one, select the new certificate file which you have exported from the website. Give a suitable name and click ok. Thats it. you are done.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.webupd8.org/2010/11/fix-pidgin-msn-omegacontactsmsncom.html