# How can I solve a Pidgin certificate error?

Tags: security, pidgin, certification

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where does Ubuntu store the SSL certificates for Pidgin?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13837/where-does-ubuntu-store-the-ssl-certificates-for-pidgin)

Changing my ~/.purple/certificates to certificates.old doesn't solved.

> Unable to validate certificate
>
> The certificate for
>   omega.contacts.msn.com could not be
>   validated. The certificate chain
>   presented is invalid.

Any idea how to make pidgin work?